# Lighttpd downloads the script instead of executing it

Tags: django, lighttpd

I'm trying to get a Django app running with Lighttpd.  I followed the directions here:

http://ca.rroll.net/2009/07/12/deploying-your-django-app-on-joyent-shared-accelerators/

But when I go to the URL, it downloads the script instead of executing it.  It seems like a MIME problem to me, but I have no idea what is missing. Of course, it could be something totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lighttpd will default undefined mimetypes to "application/octet-stream" which usually causes browsers to want to download a binary so you can open it later with the appropriate application.

You likely need to [change mimetype mapping configuration](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/lighttpd/Mimetype.assignDetails).

Comment: Sorry, I read "script" and immediately jumped to javascript. I would re-examine the fastcgi.server declaration and make sure it's correct. Also, make sure the execute bit is set on the script file. You might find additional info here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#lighttpd-setup

Comment: I took the side-wide mime.types file, converted it to lighttpd's format, and that worked.  I counted your reply as the answer.